# How do header files like OpenGL.h work

Tags: c++, opengl

I understand that header files are processed prior to compilation of the remainder of the source file in which it is included to make the process of developing code easier. I also know that they allow working declarations. however, I don't see functions in use in the header file OpenGL.h like I do in all the tutorials I have been researching. The OpenGL.h is very obscure to me with #define extern. I don't know what is happening. for instance

```
#define CGL_VERSION_1_0  1
#define CGL_VERSION_1_1  1
#define CGL_VERSION_1_2  1
#define CGL_VERSION_1_3  1


extern CGLError CGLQueryRendererInfo(GLuint display_mask,
CGLRendererInfoObj *rend, GLint *nrend);

extern CGLError CGLDestroyRendererInfo(CGLRendererInfoObj rend);
extern CGLError CGLDescribeRenderer(CGLRendererInfoObj rend, GLint
rend_num, CGLRendererProperty prop, GLint *value);
```

I have no idea what is happening here, and have come across other c++ includes that share similar obscurity. I would like to write a library of my own and I feel that popper header files are outlined in this manner.

to me it seems like all that is happening is keywords or variables are being made, or functions that don't have a code block. I have taken 2 courses in c++, introduction and c++ but they did not touch on this topic in very much detail.

I am just trying to deobfuscate what is happening.

Comment: What exactly confuses you? Absence of opengl functions implementations in the header? Or, probably, the extern keyword?

Comment: Absence of OpenGL functions mainly. I am sure that I can probably find the answer to the extern keyword myself

Comment: some headers/libs can be indeed very convoluted, however 2 introduction courses is not that much.

Comment: Are the accompanied .cpp files containing the functions for the headers located in the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, library headers do not contain implementations (exceptions are, for example, header-only libraries, especially with loads of c++ template code). Headers just provide information on how to call library functions, that is, data types and signatures. The implementation is usually contained in a [static or shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)).

Strictly speaking, OpenGL is not even a library, but a specification, while OpenGL implementation is usually provided as a shared library. That is, the implementation of OpenGL functions is stored as a bunch of binary data holding compiled code. If you really want the sources, you need to check which implementation of OpenGL are you using (it could be nvidia drivers, for example, and I doubt that the real sources are available).

In order to understand, how this compiled code gets linked with your code and how headers are involved in this process, I recommend you to read more about C++ compillation process and static and dynamic linking.

Comment: @ShenRuki: If you are going to write portable GL code, then some library such as GLEW will manage the GL awkward linker issues, because they are somewhat unique with respect to other C libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the name `OpenGL.h` might suggest otherwise, you're not looking at the OpenGL header file. This is the header for CGL, which is the window system interface for OpenGL on Mac OS.

The window system interface is a platform dependent layer that forms the "glue" between OpenGL and the window system on the platform. This API is used to configure and create contexts, drawing surfaces, etc. It corresponds to WGL on Windows, GLX on Linux, EGL on Android, EAGL on iOS, etc.

If you want to see the actual OpenGL headers, look for `gl.h` and `gl3.h` in the same directory. `gl.h` is for legacy OpenGL 2.1, `gl3.h` is for the core profile of OpenGL 3.x and later.

Those headers contain the declarations of the OpenGL API entry points, as well as definitions for enums. The functions need to be declared so that you can call them in your code. In C++, you cannot call undeclared functions.

The code for the functions is in the OpenGL framework, which you link against. A framework on Mac OS is a package that contains headers, libraries, and some related files. It's the libraries within the framework that contain the actual implementation of the API entry points.

Comment: Thank you very much. You clarified what I asked quite well. even some new information I was interested in and did not ask for.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL, you have to retrieve a pointer to each OpenGL function ere it can be used; they are thus loaded in run-time. That pointer becomes the function itself albeit typedef'd in order to appear as a function. There are libraries that do this for you like glew, glLoadGen, glbinding to name the most prominent ones. OpenGL.h would hold function pointers and maybe some contextual information on how to initialise OpenGL.

Headers only contain function prototypes; but with OpenGL it's different because you would instead hold only the pointer to the function rather than the actual function itself.

Comment: So there is more to a framework file than the header files.

Comment: Suffice it to say that OpenGL functions are already implemented; therefore you would have to load them first before using. CGL is a Mac OS X framework, so you won't have to load your OpenGL functions in run-time. But, if you were to port your application to another operating system like Linux, then you'll have to load your functions.

Comment: Based on the header file, the OP is using Mac OS, where function loading is not needed. You're probably thinking of Windows or Linux.